# Holomorphic extension using reflection principle

Tags: complex-analysis, reflection

I cannot really understand how the reflection principle works. I have found various forms of the theorem, but the notes i use are not so clear on how we actually extend functions and what is the formula used each time. So i gathered two examples i need help with. Hopefully their solutions will make things clearer for me. Here it goes:

1) Let $D$ be the unit disc, $I=\left \{ e^{it}:t\in(0,1) \right \}$ an open arc on its the boundary and a function $f$ continuous on $D\cup I$ and holomorphic on $D$. If $f(z)=e^z$ for $z\in I$, show that $f$ has an expansion which is entire.

[Related: if $f$ is instead identically zero on that arc, how can we extend-reflect in order to make $I$ be a set whose points are interior points of a new domain and analytically continuate so that we get that $f$ is identically zero everywhere?]

2) Let $H$ be the upper half-plane, $I=[0,1]$ and let $f:H\cup I\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function, holomorphic on $H$, satistfying $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+i}$ for every $x\in [0,1]$.Show that $f$ has a extension F on $D=\left \{ z:|z+i|>\frac{1}{3} \right \}$.

All help will be welcome and appreciated.

Comment: are you sure $f(z)$ is continuous only on $|z| < 1 \cup I$ and not on the whole closed unit disk ? Because in that case, and if $f(z)$ vanishes on $I$, I get $f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_1^{2 \pi} \frac{f(e^{it})}{1 - z e^{-it}} dt$

Comment: That troubled me as well, because you can transfer the problem to the upper half-plane using a Mobius transformation, which sends the open arc to an open interval. So we have the classic reflection principle at our disposal and that extends $f$ only on the symmetric domain which is the two planes along with the interval, not all the line in which it is contained, namely $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, returning back to the disc with the inverse Mobius, you bring back an extension with it, but just on the plane minus the rest of the unit circle we had from the start. How can it be entire?...

Comment: Another idea: reflect directly, the inversion on the unit circle is $\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ so the extension is $F(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}f(z), z\in D\cup I
\\ 1/ \overline{f\left ( \frac{1}{\bar{z}} \right )}, z\in D*
\end{matrix}\right.$. Still, a meromorphic function. If we had that $f$ is continuous on the whole unit disc, things would be easy. By the previous argument for $g(z)=f(z)-e^z$, we go to $H$ and $f$ is extended. Since it is zero on $I$ then $g$ is zero everywhere and we get the result by analytic continuation: $f(z)=e^z$, an entire function.

Comment: How did you end up with that equation? Any thoughts about what i said and/or the second example?

Comment: ok yes, that works. Now I recall the theorem : if $g(z)$ is holomorphic on an upper-rectangle $T > Im(z) > 0, Re(z) \in (-1,1)$ and continuous when $Im(z) \to 0^+$ and real on $Im(z)=0$, then extending by $g(\overline{z})=\overline{g(z)}$ makes it holomorphic on the whole rectangle $Re(z) \in (-1,1), |Im(z)| < T$. So all we need is a bi-holomorphic map sending $I$ to an open interval (what you wrote), consider $g(z) =f(z) - e^z$ and voila, we get a function holomorphic on an open containing $I$, vanishing on $I$, i.e. it is everywhere $0$ (and it is trivially extendable to an entire function)

Comment: so to me the trick is to consider at first that $g(z)$ is real on $I$ (not identically $0$) to extend it to an holomorphic function on $U \supset I$ (Möbius transforming, applying the [Schwartz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) and inverse Möbius transforming) and say that $g \equiv 0$ on $I \implies g \equiv 0$  on $U$

Comment: Still, we only have continuity on $I$ and that is for sure. Nothing special about this arc, in fact any open arc of positive length will do. The case in which $f$ is continuous on the whole unit circle is treated as a special and easy one.

Comment: in my 2 last comments I only supposed it was continuous on $D \cup I$ as you said, and used the Schwarz reflection principle to extend it to the other side of $I$ (as you did with $F(z)$, but for $G(z)$ instead)

Comment: I was not careful, my mind got stuck! It seems you are right, the key is to make $I$ a set of interior points for a new domain, it doesn't matter if we can extend to the whole plane. We even avoid the Mobius' pole (even then, we could confine ourselves to a smaller arc, i think). We first prove that such a $g$ is zero everywhere, which can of course be extended to an entire function, thus $f(z)=e^z$ everywhere, an entire function as requested. Thanks for the insight! Any thoughts on the second one? My guess is we just need to apply known formulas, right?

Comment: What I recall from all this : if $h(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$, real on a smooth curve $I \subset \partial U$ and  continuous on $U \cup I$, then (by a bi-holomorphic map sending $I$ to $(0,1)$ and the Schwarz reflection principle) it is extendable to an holomorphic function on an open $V \supset I$